# creating roulette simulator in python

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and need assistance in creating a virtual roulette simulator. I am currently working on red and I am able to randomly generate a number out of 36. However, when I try to compare if the randomly generated number is equal to either red or black, I get no output. Any help would be more than appreciated. Thank you.

```
import random

funds = 0
all_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36]
red = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35]
black = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36]

print('Welcome to Python Roulette Simulator!')
while True:
    choice = input('\nSelect from the following; [a]dd funds, [r]ed, [b]lack, [o]dd, [e]ven, [n]umbers: ')

    if choice == 'a':
        funds = int(input('How much money do you wish to take out? (e.g. for $500 type 500): '))

    elif choice == 'r':
        print('You currently have $', funds, 'in your account.')
        red_bet = int(input('\nHow much money will you put on red: '))

        if red_bet > funds:
            print('You do not have enough funds to bet that amount. Please place a lower bet or add more funds.')

        elif funds >= red_bet:
            funds = funds - red_bet
            print('\nSpinning the wheel!')

            spin = random.choice(all_numbers)

            print('The wheel landed on', spin)

            if spin == red:
                print('Congratulations!')

            elif spin == black:
                print('You lost.')
```

Comment: `if spin in red:` - You want to test if the number is **in** the list, not equal to the list.

Comment: As a side note: `all_numbers = list(range(1, 37))`, `red = list(range(1, 36, 2))`, `black = list(range(2, 37, 2))` is shorter than writing the list yourself...

Comment: As another note, you're roulette misses the `0`, the bank will not be happy with that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `spin` is a single number from all numbers. `red` is a list of numbers.
To check if a specific number is in a list, you can use `if spin in red:`.